# Eliminating NaN Values from an array in C

Tags: arrays, c, algorithm

I was trying to clean "NaN" variables in a given array example;
My input array A is:

```
float A[] = { 5.0f, NAN, 1.5f, 0.0f, 1.75f };
```

Expected output array A is:

```
{5.0f,1.5f, 0.0f, 1.75f}
```

I can delete each NAN and shift the elements one time to left.
But if the array is too big to handle, it will become inefficient algorithm.

I couldn't find any solution in C.
So my question is there any more efficient solution than these approach?

Regards.

Comment: (a) What do you mean by “shift the elements one time to left”? Show code, or at least pseudo-code, explaining what you mean. (b) An array in C is a set of contiguously allocated objects of a particular type. If the output array is to contain the non-NaN values, they **must** be moved to that location. There is no way around that if the output is to be an array. There may be fast ways to do it, and there may be ways to manage the data other than as an array.

Comment: I mean, I can detect "NaN" value. Then get the indice (for instance a) of that variable. It will seem like array[a] = array[a+1] until the last element of array.

Comment: There is no need to iterate on `array[a] = array[a+1]` each time you find a NaN. Can you think of another algorithm?

Comment: Alright, for example if I was using Modern C++ I can use STL library and vector as container and all the job is just using erase method. So I was looking a solution like that in C.

Comment: You have to fill the gaps somehow....

Comment: Suppose you had a bunch of red and blue blocks lined up in front of you, left to right, and you wanted to eliminate all the blue blocks, moving the red blocks to the left. Would you go to the first (leftmost) blue block, remove it, and shift all the blocks right of that left one, and then go to the second blue block, remove it, and shift all the blocks right of that left one, and keep repeating? Or would you move the blocks in a different way? What way?

Comment: The first method that came to mind was to record the steps until each NAN value is found in an array. After entering and changing the "NaN" values in the array using these numbers (indices) that I got after coming to the last element of the array, I thought of "shift" the whole array as many as these numbers gradually. 
Example if my NaN values in 3. and 5. position. I will record their positions another array. After finding whole NaN values. I will look these array and move the elements depend on that position info. But this still sounds bad algorithm, so I came here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an `O(n)` solution using [two pointers technique](https://leetcode.com/articles/two-pointer-technique/?page=1#). It's posible to swap all `NaN` terms to the end of the array while preserving relative ordering of non `NaN` terms.
`p` keeps the record of how many non `NaN` terms are encountered and its returned to keep track of current size of `A`.

```c
int moveNAN(float A[], int n)
{
    int p = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        if(!isnan(A[i]))  // if `isnan` is not defined use `A[i] == A[i]` (NaN values return false)
        {
            if(p != i)
                swap(A[i], A[p]);
            ++p;
        }
    return p;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Eliminating NaN Values from an array in C

There is little special here about NaN.  To eliminate a value from an array, walk the array.

```
// `isnan()`
#include <math.h>

// In place solution
float A[] = { 5.0f, NAN, 1.5f, 0.0f, 1.75f };
size_t n = sizeof A/sizeof A[0];
size_t w = 0; 
for (size_t r = 0; r < n; r++) {
  if (!isnan(A[r]) {
    A[w++] = A[r];
  }
}
// Array size is still `n`, yet the first `w` elements are of interest.
```

To make a new array, code could form a VLA and walk `A[]` twice, first to determine size, 2nd to read and copy.

```
// New array solution
float A[] = { 5.0f, NAN, 1.5f, 0.0f, 1.75f };
size_t n = sizeof A/sizeof A[0];

size_t new_n = 0;
for (size_t r = 0; r < n; r++) {
  if (!isnan(A[r]) new_n++;
}

if (new_n == 0) TBD_code();  // VLA must be at least 1
float new_A[new_n];
size_t w = 0; 
for (size_t r = 0; r < n; r++) {
  if (!isnan(A[r]) {
    new_A[w++] = A[r];
  }
}
```